# how to spend 100 hour training after finishing google data analytics certificate properly?

Tags: capstone

I am near finishing google data analytics certificate, I want to spend 100 hours doing projects and building an amazing portfolio to get a decent online job as a data analyst .. what projects should I focus on ?, where to find them ?

At the end of studying the certificate, there is a capstone , how can I gain decent experience and differentiate my self afterwards ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all congratulations on completion!

1. You can focus on following projects: `Dashboard Creation`: create dashboard using any visualization tool like Power BI. It should include relevant metrics. Another project is `Data Analysis Exploration`: choose any dataset and perform data analysis. You can Python or R to analyze and create visualization. Another one is `A/B Testing`: choose any website and design A/B test to evaluate the impact.
2. You can find datasets from open sources like `kaggle.com`
3. To differentiate yourself after completing the capstone project, you can show your projects in your `portfolio`, don't forget to put them in `GitHub`. And be active in community forms